# Clear margin and padding from chart.js graphs

Tags: chart.js

I'm working with the Chart.js v2 library and want to achieve following result:

[image]

Chart.js has a build in padding and margin renderd in their canvas. 
Is there any method of setting this to 0 to achieve the result above.

Currently I can make it look like:
[image]

As you can see the graph is not completely fitted to the canvas,
instead the left and right side have a small empty extension of the graph.

Below is the config I used for the following result:

```
            options: {
               responsive: true,
               maintainAspectRatio: false,
               legend: {
                        display: false,
                    },
               scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                     gridLines: {
                        display: true,
                        color: '#eff3f6',
                        zeroLineColor: '#fff',
                        zeroLineWidth: 0,
                        drawBorder: false,
                        tickMarkLength: 0
                     },
                    ticks: {
                       display: false,
                       beginAtZero: true
                    }
              ],
                 yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                       display: true,
                       color: '#eff3f6',
                       zeroLineColor: '#fff',
                       zeroLineWidth: 0,
                       drawBorder: false,
                       tickMarkLength: 0
                     },
                     ticks: {
                        display: false,
                        beginAtZero: true
                     }
                  }]
               }
            }
```

Comment: Have you double checked that there is no padding set in the container holding your canvas object?  I ask, because when I did a test of rendering a single chart on a page inside of a div, I see no padding that you are demonstrating.  The graph bumps right up to the edges on all sides.

Comment: Hello, there is a padding yes. but it's not the padding I'm referring to.
It indeed bumbs to the side, but you can still see the line is drawn further at the left and bottom.

Comment: Can you include your chart.js config in your question?